# Linearly independent amount

Tags: linear-algebra

**Statement:**
If $v_1=[2;1;11;2]$, $v_2=[1;0;4;-1]$, $v_3=[11;4;56;5]$ and $v_4=[2;-1;5;-6]$, then $(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$ is a linearly independent set.

**My answer:**
I think that they are linearly independent. Am I correct?

Comment: Put them into a 4x4 matrix, calculate the determinant and you'll know for sure.

Comment: okey. i will try

Comment: I've calculated it and it turns out to be $0$. So these vectors are linearly dependent unless I've made a mistake.

Comment: you are correct. I did write wrong. it is linearly dependent

Comment: The English term for Swedish “mängd” is “set” rather than “amount”.

Answer (score 0):

You are not correct; you can consider the matrix having those vectors as columns and do Gaussian elimination on it
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 11 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & 4 & -1 \\
11 & 4 & 56 & 5 \\
2 & -1 & 5 & -6
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 4 & -1 \\
2 & 1 & 11 & 2 \\
11 & 4 & 56 & 5 \\
2 & -1 & 5 & -6
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_1\leftrightarrow R_2 \\[6px]
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 4 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 3 & 4 \\
0 & 4 & 12 & 16 \\
0 & -1 & -3 & -4
\end{bmatrix}
&& \begin{aligned}
   R_2 &\gets R_2-2R_1 \\ R_3&\gets R_3-11R_1 \\ R_4 &\gets R_4-2R_1
   \end{aligned} \\[6px]
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 4 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 3 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
&& \begin{aligned} R_3&\gets R_3-4R_2 \\ R_4 &\gets R_4+R_2 \end{aligned}
\end{align}
From the last matrix, which is the reduced row echelon form, it follows that
$$
v_3=4v_1+3v_2,\qquad v_4=-v_1+4v_2
$$
This method is more efficient than computing the determinant, which only tells you that the set is linearly dependent, but doesn't show the linear relations between the vectors.